# Implementing a java class and testing many conditions in a method

Tags: java, object, constructor

I must implement a Java class which "simulates" an object called Student. Student objects from this class represent 
student grade records. There are 12 variables, 3 constructors, and 12 methods.

There is a pre-writed application and text file (neither shown here) that will populate all the data 
fields in each student object and store a reference to each student object in an array.

The parts I'm having the most trouble with are (1) How do I create the constructors properly? 
(2) How do I properly create the methods like setHomework which take arguments, compare them 
against multiple conditions within a method, and assigns them to an array element?

Anyway, this is the incomplete code I have so far:

```
public class Student{ 

private String name;

private String sid;

private double homework = NUM_HOMEWORK; //reference variable 

private double quizzes = NUM_QUIZZES; //reference variable 

private double exams = NUM_EXAMS; //reference variable 

final static int NUM_HOMEWORK = 4;

final static int NUM_QUIZZES = 4;

final static int NUM_EXAMS = 2;

final static double HOMEWORK_MAX_POINTS = 5;

final static double QUIZ_MAX_POINTS = 20;

final static double MIDTERM_MAX_POINTS = 40;

final static double FINAL_MAX_POINTS = 60;


/*1st constructor. No-arg constructor. Sets object’s name variable to default value “Newstudent, A.” and object’s sid var to default of “0000000”.  Also allocates 3 arrays; homework with length of NUM_HOMEWORK, quizzes with length of NUM_QUIZZES, and exams with length of NUM_EXAMS.*/
Student(){ 
   name = "Newstudent, A";
   sid = "0000000";
   int[] homework = new int[NUM_HOMEWORK];
   int[] quizzes = new int[NUM_QUIZZES];
   int[] exams = new int[NUM_EXAMS];
}



/*2nd constructor. Takes 1 string arg and stores it in parameter newName.  Param represents the name of a new Student object.  Constructor sets object’s name var to the given newName and object’s sid var to default value of “0000000”.  Also allocates same three arrays as first constructor.*/ 
Student(String newName) {
   name = newName;
   sid = "0000000";
   int[] homework = new int[NUM_HOMEWORK];
   int[] quizzes = new int[NUM_QUIZZES];
   int[] exams = new int[NUM_EXAMS];
}


/*3rd constructor. Takes 2 string args and stores them in string params newName and newSid. Params represent the name and sid of a new Student object. Constructor sets object’s name var to the given newName and object’s sid var to the given newSid.  Also allocates same three arrays as first constructor*/
Student(String newName, newSid){ 
   name = newName;
   newSid = "0000000";
   int[] homework = new int[NUM_HOMEWORK];
   int[] quizzes = new int[NUM_QUIZZES];
   int[] exams = new int[NUM_EXAMS];
}

/*Method takes string arg and stores it in string newName.  Sets object’s name variable to newName.  Returns void.*/
public static void setName(String newName){ 
   name = newName;
}

public static getName(){//Takes no args. Returns value of the object’s name variable.
   return String name;
}

/*Takes 1 String arg and stores it in string param newSid. Sets object’s sid var to the given newSid.  Returns void.*/
public static void setSid(String newSid){   
   sid = newSid;
}

/*Takes an int arg and stores it in int param homeworkNumber, and a double arg and stores it in double param score.  Method checks if homeworkNumber is a # between 1 and NUM_HOMEWORK and if score is a # between 0 and HOMEWORK_MAX_POINTS. If both those conditions are true it assigns the corresponding element of the homework array the value of score. Example: if homeworkNumber is 1 and score is 5 the element homework[0] is assigned value of 5.  Returns void.*/
public static void setHomework(int homeworkNumber, double score){  
   if(homeworkNumber > 1 && homeworkNumber < NUM_HOMEWORK && score > 0 && score < HOMEWORK_MAX_POINTS)
   then score = homework;
}

/*Takes one int arg and stores it in a param homeworkNumber.  Method returns one of the values in the object’s homework array.  Method checks if homeworkNumber is # between 1 and NUM_HOMEWORK, and if this condition is true, method returns the double value at index homeworkNumber – 1 in the homework array.  Otherwise, method returns 0.  Method returns double.*/
public static getHomework(int homeworkNumber){ 
   if(homeworkNumber > 1 && homeworkNumber < NUM_HOMEWORK)
   then return homeworkNumber – 1;    
   else return 0;
}

/*Method takes an int param named quizNumberand and a double param named score.  Method checks if quizNumber is a between 1 and NUM_QUIZZES and if score is between 0 and QUIZ_MAX_POINTS. If both conditions are true assigns the corresponding element of the quizzes array the value of score.  Example: if quizNumber is 1 and score is 18 the element quiz[0] is assigned 18. Method returns void.*/
public static void setQuiz(int quizNumber, double score){       
      if (quizNumber > 1 && quizNumber < NUM_QUIZZES && score > 0 && score < QUIZ_MAX_POINTS) 
      quizzes = score; 
}

/*Takes one int arg and stores it in param quizNumber.  Returns one of the values in the object’s quizzes array.  Method checks if quizNumber is between 1 and NUM_QUIZZES and if true returns the value at index quizNumber – 1 in the quizzes array.  Otherwise, method returns 0. Method returns double.*/
public static getQuiz(int quizNumber){ 
      if(quizNumber > 1 && quizNumber < NUM_QUIZZES) 
      return double quizNumber[] – 1        
      else return 0; 
}

/*Takes one double args, stores it in param score. Checks if score is between 0 and MIDTERM_MAX_POINTS and if true, assign the element exams[0] the value of score.  Returns void.*/
public static void setMidtermExam(double score){  

     if(score > 0 && score < MIDTERM_MAX_POINTS)
     score = exams[0];      
}

public static getMidtermExam(){//Takes no args. Return double value of exams[0].  
    return exams[0];   
}

/*Takes one double arg, stores in in param score. Checks if score is between 0 and FINAL_MAX_POINTS and iff true assigns exams[1] the value of score. Method returns void.*/
public static void setFinalExam(double score){ 
if (score > 0 && score < FINAL_MAX_POINTS)
    score = exams[1];
}

public static getFinalExam(){ //Takes no args. Returns double value of exams[1].  
return exams[1];
}

/*Takes no args. Returns a String which the student object’s name, sid, homework scores, quiz scores and exam scores are concatenated.*/
public static toString(){  
return "Student total information. " + name + ", " + sid + ", homework: " + homework + ", quizzes: " + quizzes + ", exams: " + exams;
}



}
```

Comment: Seems like you have the constructors. You can create new constructors if you need more parameters to be passed. From those constructors, if you need to have logic to setHomework, you can call the setter for that value. If you are using an IDE, it should generate the base code for you and then you can add more features from there. Also...the constructors need to be public.

Comment: public Student(String newName, String newSid){... }

Comment: public static void setHomework(int homeworkNumber, double score){  
   if(homeworkNumber > 1 && homeworkNumber < NUM_HOMEWORK && score > 0 && score < HOMEWORK_MAX_POINTS)
   then homework[homeworkNumber-1] = score;
}

Answer (score 0):

Constructor:

```
public Student(String newName, String newSid){... }
```

setHomework:

```
public static void setHomework(int homeworkNumber, double score) {
    if (homeworkNumber > 1 && homeworkNumber < NUM_HOMEWORK && score > 0 && score < HOMEWORK_MAX_POINTS) {
        homework[homeworkNumber - 1] = score;
    }
}
```

> homework

is declared as a double but I think you meant for it to be an array?

```
private double[] homework;
```